# Accessing strings through segues on ios 5

Tags: ios, xcode, string, storyboard, segue

I've got a question concerning my Storyboard. I want to change the value of a string which is in ViewA through a segue. That means that ViewB should do the segue and in preparation for that changing the value of the string in ViewA. My problem is now, that the value of my string stays unchanged.

ViewA.h file:

```
@interface NewViewController : UITableViewController <MKAnnotation>
{
    NSString *longString;

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *longString;
```

ViewB.m file:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"transmitCoordsToNew"])
    {
        NewViewController *controller = (NewViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.longString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", segueLong];    

    }
}
```

Any idea why the variables stay unchanged or why I can't see any changes on further operating in ViewA?

Thanks in advance,

Phil

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where your variable segueLong comes from, but having a weak reference to longString is most likely what's causing the problem. Change that to a strong reference and see if it works then.

Comment: Okay, I changed the String ("longString") to a strong reference but the debugger shows (while putting a breakpoint after the prepareForSegue method) that the longString is still empty. I have no clue why it remains nil, although I've changed it...

Comment: Edit: Basically I discovered that the String is wiped, when the segue is finished..

Comment: You set it to the value of longString. I'm assuming this is an ivar, as you're not getting any errors. Check the value (and type, it should be a float) of longString, it's probably not what you expect it to be.

Comment: I checked the value and it's alright... As i said, the value of the string is correct until the segue is finished. When the segue is done, the string turns into nil.

Comment: Well, then I would suggest finding out where exactly the value is changed. Check it immediately after setting it, then at the end (right before the }) of prepareForSegue, and at the beginning/end of viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear. At some point this value changes, and I'm betting it doesn't do so by itself. I'm still leaning toward "it's being released", but if you say you changed it to a strong reference, that doesn't seem possible to me...

Comment: Okay, I checked out some breakpoints and revealed that the strings are written until they leave the segue. Which means: The last line before the } of the prepareForSegue reveals that the strings are written but the viewWillAppear-method of the NewViewController already shows that the strings are empty (nil). longString has the strong property just like HeadNinja proposed me…

Comment: Could it be that the problem is resulting of the fact that the segueing comes from another thread?

Comment: A segue is a UI thing, which always has to be executed on the main thread.

Comment: Does this mean that prepareForSegue also comes from the main thread? I'm just wondering why the string becomes nil when the NewViewController is about to appear...

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think it does get executed from the main thread. I you're working with different threads, the code you have posted is not complete. The code as you post it should work, but threads could mess the whole thing up. Include more code, or even the whole project.

Comment: I have no extra threads (if you think of NSThread). I've checked everything once again: Everything is synthesized, longString is 'strong' and the values, that go into longString, are correct. They are even written into the longString! But when NewView is appearing they are wiped... Why?

Comment: The setter method also doesn't work. String values become empty after segue.

Comment: Is there a possibility to check out if the string really is 'strong'? Or to protect the string of releasing it (making it 'nil')?

Answer (score 0):

If in prepareForSegue your `NewViewController *controller` is receiving a valid (non nil) value from `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", segueLong];` I am about 90% sure that the 'weak' property attribute is responsible for the value turning to nil.

Here's why!

[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", segueLong] has a scope limited by the prepareForSegue method, also it has no owner (aka no reference is counted for it).  Even if segueLong has an owner and will not be released by arc, the resulting NSString from stringWithFormat does not!

What you need to do is change weak, to strong.
:

```
@interface NewViewController : UITableViewController <MKAnnotation>
{
    __strong NSString *longString;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *longString;
```

This ensures that the string generated by NSString stringWithFormat will belong to your NewViewController!

Comment: I did it as you said, but this does not work. I also checked out Scotts proposition but still no solution on this...

Comment: Hmmm.  I am puzzled.  I am also having a similar problem in which a strong variable is being turned to nil (idk if it's actually being freed) without me realizing it.  I'll let you know if I have any insights.

Comment: Hey Phil. Are you sure that the object that gets setlongString